# divide data and copy other cells in google sheets or excel

Tags: excel, google-apps-script, google-sheets

Goodday, please i need help, i have data scattered over different cells in a google sheet, cell one contains a name, cell2 contains many lines with data, and cell 3 contains a name, i need to divide the data in cell 2 into different vertical cells with copying the data in both cell 1 and 3 as shown in the attached pictures[[image: required situationenter image description here]][image: (https://i.stack.imgur.com/DHu8U.png)]

i tried transpose but it failed

Comment: Why does your sheet start on the righthand side? 

Comment: @NEWAZA because some countries work from right to left. Common knowledge.

Comment: You could look at the use of index() and match()

Comment: Common knowledge lol

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Google Apps Script, try:

```
const Sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(`YourSheetName`)

function dataHandler() {

  const dataRange = Sheet.getDataRange()
                         .offset(1, 0)
  
  const data = dataRange.getValues()

  const newValues = data.flatMap(([ name, location, addresses, phone]) => {
    
    const addressList = addresses.split(`\n`)

    return location.split(`\n`)
                   .map((item, index) => {
      return [
        name,
        (addressList[index]) ? addressList[index] : ``,
        item,
        phone
      ]
    })

  })

  dataRange.clearContent()

  Sheet.getRange(2, 1, newValues.length, newValues[0].length)
       .setValues(newValues)

}
```

Would comment this out, but currently phone-posting.

Answer (score 0):

Transpose works for me if you split: `=TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(B2, CHAR(10)))`

Assuming it's only four lines in the second cell you can just directly reference the name cells surrounding those results; that would be easiest.

EDIT: Since the number of lines is unknown you can do the following to duplicate the names: `=TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(REPT(";"&A2,COUNTIF(SPLIT(B2, CHAR(10)),"<>")), ";", TRUE, TRUE))`

What this snippit does it count the number of lines in B2, duplicate A2 that number of times with some delimiter, then splits that (removing empty lines) and transposes it same as we did for B2.

Comment: but this can't help copying the documents from other cells, other than that it's not limited to 4 lines in the second cell

Comment: @user20795119 I'm not sure what you mean about not copying the documents from other cells? That is what it's doing. If you want the raw values afterwords and not the formula, you can select it and right-click -> copy values only.  Also added how to duplicate names.